# Web app on a VPS. How to make it appear on a subdomain?

Tags: reverse-proxy, virtualhost, port, apache2, subdomain

I'm using a personal VPS (Ubuntu 20, Apache2) to host a web app. Currently there are 2 static sites, site1.com and site2.org, both working.

I installed an app that is currently available on port 8065, e.g.: `site2.org:8065`

My question is, how can I set up Apache to make the app appear at **mm.site2.org**? (with the subdomain "mm").

I created a config file like this:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/mm.site2.org.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mm.site2.org

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy http://localhost:8065/*>       
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
        
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8065/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8065/

    <Location />
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

After setting up the above, I've run the requisite commands to restart the services like this:

```
sudo a2ensite mm.site2.org.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I've also tried a variant of the `<Proxy ...>` line in the Apache conf file, based on some different sources, using simply `<Proxy *>` as some sources suggest.

If it is relevant, my DNS settings consist simply of two A records (`@` and `www`) for each site.

The output of `sudo apache2ctl -S` is:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 12.345.67.890. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server site1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost site1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.site1.com
         port 443 namevhost site2.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2.org-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.site2.org
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 12.345.67.890 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 12.345.67.890 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost site1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.site1.com
         port 80 namevhost site2.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2.org.conf:1)
                 alias www.site2.org
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

No luck getting the webapp to appear on the subdomain desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you write, I think DNS isn't properly configured:

> If it is relevant, my DNS settings consist simply of two A records (@
> and www) for each site.

You must add a DNS RR for a subdomain, address: `mm.site2.org. A 12.345.67.890`, or cname (alias): `mm.site2.org. CNAME www.site2.org.`. To direct all subdomains to this server RR name may be a wildcard: `*.site2.org. A 12.345.67.890` (CNAME RR will probably suffice too). (It seems you expected it already works like this.)

Comment: Thanks! This worked. You're right... I thought that *either* I needed to configure Apache, *or* I needed to set up another DNS entry. I apparently should have considered *both* :-) (I had already attempted to set another DNS entry, but I was focusing on CNAME. I didn't format it properly, NameCheap's validation was complaining, and I concluded from that that I must focus on Apache.)

For others' benefit, the resource record I set was of type A, with simply "mm" for host and 12.345.67.890 for value.

Cheers!

Comment: Just for clarity: simple "mm" would get converted to "mm.site2.org." under the origin (context) of "site2.org." undet the hood. I wrote that in the most explicit form, because I didn't knew anything about features of zone editing interface available to you. Note dots at the end. The rule is: if the name ends with a dot, nothing needs to be appended (that's compete explicit form), if the name doesn't end with a dot, active context value needs to be appended (that may be origin if we talk about zone, or dns suffix if we talk about name resolution on a computer).